# How to convert CSV file from two sources(excel,json) in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, export-to-csv, node-modules

I have list of car names and description in the excel sheet. So i need to read the excel file and search against the system using REST api call and finally take top result value to csv file including source of car name and description.

Using below code i can able to convert json to csv file but how to include source excel file content into csv file?

Please advise.

Excel input:

```
Car name, Description
Honda   , some description
```

API response data:

```
[{
    "total": 10,
    "results": [{
      "name": {
        "val": "Honda",
        "id": "0271b276",
        "type": "String",
      },
      "attributes": [{
        "val": "accord",
        "type": "field1",

      },  {
        "val": "test123",
        "type": "field3",
      }],

    }]
  },

]
```

Expectation output in the CSV file.

```
Car Name , Description,Total results,Make  , Model
honda    , Description,10           , Honda, accord
```

Code

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const xlsx = require('xlsx');

const workbook = xlsx.readFile(__dirname + '/test.xlsx');
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
for (let z in worksheet) {
  if(z.toString()[0] === 'A'){

request({
    url: 'http://url', //URL to hit
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        query: worksheet[z].v, 

    }
}, function(error, response, data){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {




    var fields = ['Make','Model','total', 'results[0].name.val','results[0].name[0].val'];
    var fieldNames = ['Make','Model','Total','Name','Description'];

    var opts1 = {
       data: data,
      fields: fields,
      fieldNames: fieldNames,

    };

    var json2csv = require('json2csv');
    var csv = json2csv(opts1);

    fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('file saved');
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert XLS to CSV on the server in Node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342425/convert-xls-to-csv-on-the-server-in-node)

Comment: No, This is two source input (json,excel) to csv.