# Parsing/Converting big XLSX (over 600MB) to CSV in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, csv, xlsx

I've got a problem with converting big XLSX which is over 600mb to CSV. The thing is that with smaller files(>3MB) it's fine, but when it comes to big files then I can see how it eats up the whole memory and then just create an empty test.csv file.
So far I used this module: node-xlsx
I follow the guide here: [Convert XLS to CSV on the server in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342425/convert-xls-to-csv-on-the-server-in-node)

Comment: Just curious why are you trying to parse it to a csv?  Do you have an example of your xls  and what your would like the output to look like in the csv?

Comment: xlsx is just simple sheet with a lots of columns and some data in them, no graphs or any visual object in there.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you are following works fine for smaller files. However [XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) is the most famous one.

But it will also fail for large files due to restriction on Node RAM usage.

> You can increase the allowed RAM by --max_old_space_size=4096 where 4096=4GB

Answer (score 0):

These answers are not solving the memory issue.

If you load entire Excel and or Array in memory it can get take up a lot of memory, often more then 1gb.

The way to deal with extremely large datasets (1 million+) and not crash your server is not load things in the memory and use streams:

```
        import Excel from 'exceljs';

        const workbook_write_stream = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({
          filename: filePath,
        });

        const sheet = workbook_write_stream.addWorksheet('Data');
    
        sheet.addRow(rowHeaders).commit();
    
        for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
            const data = await this.makePostRequest(searchId, i);

    
            const rows = data.records;
    
            for (const row of rows) {
              const formattedRow = [];
    
              rowHeaders.forEach((header) => {
                formattedRow.push(row[header]);
              });
    
            }

        }
    
        sheet.commit();
        await workbook_write_stream.commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

My main issue with the big sheet not working was that I was on `node: v7.10.1 (with npm 4.2.0)` after I upgraded to `node: v14.17.0 (with npm 6.14.13)`. I also used `--max-old-space-size=4096` when running my node script.

### [Node XLSX](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx)

I only started using this one after SheetJS was outputting no data because of the larger sheets. I used this solution with [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/) because I find it easy to use.

```js
const xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
const Papa = require('papaparse');
const fs = require('fs');

var obj = xlsx.parse(inputPath);

for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var sheet = obj[i];
    fs.writeFile(`${outputPath}.${i}.csv`, Papa.unparse(sheet.data));
}
```

### [SheetJS js-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

I'm still including this solution because it worked nicely up until the issues with larger sheets, I also liked that it had CLI commands.

CLI command for converting excel to CSV:

```bash
xlsx --book -o 'output.csv' 'input.xlsx'
```

Code to do the same in node

```js
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const workBook = XLSX.readFile(inputPath);
workBook.SheetNames.forEach((sheet, idx) => {
    XLSX.writeFile(workBook, `${outputPath}.${idx}.csv`, {sheet: sheet, bookType: "csv"});
});
```

Comment: it's not solving the memory issue.

Comment: Memory issues can be tough, have you tried allocating more memory to your node script via the `--max-old-space-size` option

Comment: no it's not the point to add more memory, you have to rewrite in a way that it doesnt exceed a ceratin memory, that can be done with writing directly to file or using streams

Comment: I agree, this is not a solution to the original question. It was only a solution to my personal project. In my situation *PapaParse* helped perform my task more efficiently than *SheetJS* solving my issue, I left the answer to help others start down this path and provide an alternative library to look into. I hope someone posts a better solution.